# data not getting displayed on the reusable component in the vuejs application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

```
In my laravel vue application I'm trying to fetch total number of orders for the current day for a shopify store sing Shopify's admin REST API and display that on my vue component. 

Following is my controller

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ShopifyOrderController extends Controller
{
    public function fetchOrders()
    {
        // Set up cURL request
        $access_token = 'shpat_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $today = Carbon::today()->toIso8601String();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://API_KEY:ACCESS_TOKEN@STORE_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min={$today}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token: {$access_token}"
        ));

       // Make cURL request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        //dd($response);die;

        // Check for empty or null response
        if (empty($response) || is_null($response)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            // Return the response from the API
            return $response;
        }
    }

}
```

when I `dd($response);die;` it correctly gives me out put as `count:1` for today.

And then I have a reusable vue comonent called, `ShopifyOrdersScoreCard.vue` and following is it's code

```
<template>
    <div data-aos="fade-up" class="col-md-12 mx-1 border bg-white rounded rounded-lg w-100 h-100 py-2 px-3">
        <table class="w-100 h-100">
            <tr>
                <td class="align-top" style="height:10px">
                    <dashboard-widget-header 
                        image="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2092/100/social-35-512.png" 
                        width="32" 
                        height="32" 
                        title="Shopify" 
                        imageAlt="Shopify">
                    </dashboard-widget-header>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 class="m-b-5 custom-non-comparison-score-card-title">
                                        Orders
                                    </h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0 custom-non-comparison-score-card-value">
                                        <p 
                                            v-if="orders"
                                        >
                                            {{ orders }}
                                        </p>
                                        <p 
                                            v-else
                                        >
                                            Loading...
                                        </p>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['orders'],

    created() {
        console.log('Shopify 343434 Orders:', this.orders);
    }
}
</script>
```

Here my console log giving me `Undefined` as the out put (that's my problem, can't figure out why it's happening)

And I use this component on my `index.vue`. Following is my index.vue.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <draggable v-model="items" :options="{ group: 'shared' }" class="d-flex">
            <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" >
                <component :is="item.component" :item="item" />
            </div>
        </draggable>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShopifyOrdersScoreCard from './ShopifyOrdersScoreCard.vue';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                { id: 1, component: ShopifyOrdersScoreCard, orders: null }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchOrders() {
            // Make a request to the Laravel server to fetch the orders data
            axios.get('/orders').then(response => {
                console.log('Response:', response);
                console.log('Orders:', response.data);
                // Update the orders prop in the ShopifyOrdersScoreCard component
                this.items[0].orders = response.data;
                console.log('Items:', this.items);
            });
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchOrders();
    }
}
</script>
```

These console logs **giving** me the correct out put. but

`console.log('Shopify 343434 Orders:', this.orders);` in my `ShopifyOrdersScoreCard.vue` giving me undefined....

because of that the order count is not getting displayed on my index.vue..

Comment: Looks like. Your `prop` is expecting `orders` but you're passing `item` from index.vue. In `index.vue` try changing `:item="item"` to `:orders="item"`

Comment: hmm, I made the change then I get this as the display 
                                        {
  "id": 1,
  "component": "ShopifyOrdersScoreCard",
  "orders": {
    "count": 1
  }
}

Comment: Now you can use the dot notation to access the count i believe. `this.orders.order.count` in console. Or `{{ orders.order.count }}` in the template.